# Can you delete orders that have been archived in BigCommerce?

Tags: bigcommerce

I would like to completely delete orders from BigCommerce. So far these orders have been archived, but I would like them completely deleted so that they are not accessible from the backend of the BigCommerce CMS.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can change their status as **Shipped** and then from **Shipment** menu you can select to delete these shipments, this will delete the orders also.